# Call block with missing inputs when using auto-complete in App Inventor 2

Tags: app-inventor

I defined a procedure taking 3 inputs in [App Inventor 2](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/). How comes when I create a call block for that procedure using auto-complete the created block has no input?

[image]

From my understanding the block should be instead (which is the case when I drag the procedure from the procedure drawer):

[image]

Comment: That's a bug. Meanwhile until MIT fixed that issue, just drag the procedure from the procedure drawer instead of using [Typeblocking](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/tips/typeblocking.html)...

Comment: @Taifun Thanks, I forgot it was called typeblocking :) I reported the bug: https://code.google.com/p/app-inventor-for-android/issues/detail?id=2853

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug. Bug report: https://code.google.com/p/app-inventor-for-android/issues/detail?id=2853